# Configuring a UWP app with some configuration values

Tags: xml, uwp, config

I have a UWP app.

I want to configure it with some value, for example the ip/hostName of a server it connects to.

When i decide to change the ip/hostname, i want to change the configuration, but I don't want to enter the ip/hostName every time i run the app.

What i am searching for, is some kind of configuration table/xml/configuration that you can read from, from inside the app, and you can change externally without opening the program code.

How can i do this elegantly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use a database like SQLite or similar stuff. Can't think of anything else which will keep information even after a restart. Except a plain textfile maybe .

Answer (score 1):

If you want external file-based configuration that the user is able to edit as well, you have practically three choices:

1. Store a configuration file in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` and give the user a button in the app for example, which launches the file using `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync()`. This way the file will be stored in your app's private file store and it will be safe.
2. At first launch of the app offer the user to decide where the configuration file should be stored using `FolderPicker` or `FileSavePicker`. Then store the selected target using `StorageAccessPermissions.FutureAccessList`. This has the advantage that the user can choose a "user-friendly" location for the file and you can both access it. The picker step is required because UWP apps have limited file-system access by default, so you can't access folders outside your app directly without explicit permission. This is to ensure easy and complete uninstall and to make sure the app can't cause harm to the user's PC.
3. Opt for the restricted broad filesystem access capability. This gives you access to any location on the hard drive, but it needs to be approved during Microsoft Store certification and I am not sure if they would find saving a configuration file as a sufficient enough reason to access the whole filesystem.

Comment: what about resource files? (.resw) Can i make it possible for the user to access them?

Comment: No, those are unfortunately just resource files being compiled with your app and are stored in app install location which is not accessible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["hostname"]="yourhostname";

string hostname= (string)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["hostname"];

Comment: "you can change externally without opening the program code"

Comment: use an appservice then. it is a clr component that has access to appdata and can be accessed by all sorts of methods,

Comment: could you provide a link resource?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service